# specify specific position for collected legend in patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, patchwork

I am using the `patchwork` package in r to create panels of plots like:

```
panel<- (p1+  plot_spacer()+p2 + p3)+
    plot_layout(ncol = 2) +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
panel
```

[image]

I want to specify the legend to go to the empty top-right panel, more or less like this
[image]

Appreciate any pointers

Comment: You can use something like `cowplot::get_legend()` to make the legend its own grob, then use something like `patchwork::wrap_plots` to place the legend as if it were a graph. (After you extract the legend make the graphs without a legend.)

Answer (score 4):

For this use case `patchwork` provides `guide_area()` which could be used to place the legend:

```r
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- p2 <- p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()

p1 + guide_area() + p2 + p3 +
  plot_layout(ncol = 2) +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by @kat, one solution is to use cowplot in combination to patchwork

```
library("cowplot")
library("patchwork")
 
legend_grob <-cowplot::get_legend(p1) #get legend

#emove legend in the original plots
p1 <- p1+theme(legend.position = "none")
p2 <- p2+theme(legend.position = "none")
p3 <- p3+theme(legend.position = "none")

# now patchwork it
p1+legend_grob+p2+p3)
    plot_layout(ncol = 2)
```

[image]